# sqoop command for map-hive-columns for import-all-tables

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am importing all tables from a schema using sqoop command.The map-column-hive works fine in table level. But when I run for schema level it gives an error.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --verbose --connect "jdbcconnectionstring" --username user --password password  --hive-import --hive-database hiveschematest --map-column-hive "emptest.id=int,emptest.name=varchar(100),emptest.address=varchar(100)"  -m 1
```

I need to map some table data type with hive data types. It is giving error as "**No column name found while importing**".Whether map-hive-column support for import-all-tables(Schema) option also?

Comment: why don't you import 1 table only (_you are providing `--map-column-hive` for 1 table_)?

Comment: actually my requirement is to import all tables and some table having Binary_double data type which is not supported in hive.For that case I need map-hive-column for import-all-table option

Answer (score 0):

Try this , you have given double quotes for map-column-hive

```
sqoop import-all-tables --verbose --connect "jdbcconnectionstring" --username user --password password  --hive-import --hive-database hiveschematest --map-column-hive emptest.id=int,emptest.name=varchar(100),emptest.address=varchar(100)  -m 1
```

Comment: Still it gives the same error "No column found by the name emptest.id".

Comment: which version of sqoop you are using ? 1.4.4 ? or older ?

Comment: Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.7.1 version

Comment: they have not properly documented about this , as per the documentation it supports map-column-hive for all-table-import but they haven't talked about how to mention the database name , do one thing , I hope emptest is your database ,remove it and just mention id and try once.

Comment: I have tried it..but it is giving the same error.Moreover there should be   a placeholder to provide table name also, because two tables can have same column name.

Comment: idea scenario yes , since it is not properly documents , we need to try several options